# How to wait for a response before making the next request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I'm writing a server-only app that fetches data from an API, checks if there's anything new, and emits an update to all connections. The only restriction is that updates have to be emitted in the order that they were created (chronologically, or by pk), and a request could be affected by the response of a previous request.

The problem I'm facing is when a request takes a long time, another request might overtake it, and start emitting updates "out of turn".

What's the best way to approach this? Ideally I would like this flow:

`request -> response -> emit ... request -> response -> emit ...`

Note: If a request fails or times out, I would like to retry it at least X times.

Comment: May be you could use [Features](https://github.com/FuturesJS/sequence)

Answer (score 0):

you can use callback

```
function check(){
     //request to the api
     http.get("http://www.google.com/index.html", function(res) {
          console.log("Got response: " + res.statusCode);
          // here you can emit your events
          // do your events
          // after done your events, you can call check again
          check()
     }).on('error', function(e) {
          console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
     });
}

check()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two quick ways to counter this.

1. You can use callback and use your function recursively

   ```
   var myCall = function(){
      var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
      request.open(<request_method>, <request_url>, true);
      request.send(null);

      if (request.status === 200) {
         //put your emit function here
         myCall();
      }
   }
   myCall();
   ```
2. You can make calls synchronous. I would not recommend this if you are making continuous calls

   ```
   var myCall = function(){
      var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
      request.open(<request_method>, <request_url>, false); //false makes it synchronous
      request.send(null);

      if (request.status === 200) {
         //put your emit function here
      }
   }
   myCall();
   myCall();
   myCall();
   myCall();
   .
   .
   .
   as many times as u want
   ```

Comment: Wouldn't the first solution end up with a massive stack / overflow? What's wrong with a while(true) { myCall(); } in 2. ?

Comment: there's nothing wrong with the while statement you are trying. 
The only problem with synchronous calls is if you have any other call in you app, it would also be get blocked. 
The first one will ensure that the calls are async. and are in sequence. I don't think that it would create any stack blocking or overflow issue. You can try either.